# How to ask a confirmation before uploading a file (primeng)?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, primeng

I'm trying to ask for a confirmation before upload the file so the server, currently I have this HTML code:

```html
<p-fileUpload mode="basic" name="file" url="{{urlUpload}}" chooseLabel="Upload CSV (onBeforeSend)="onBeforeSend($event)">
```

Then, I have this TS code:

```js
onBeforeSend (event): void {
  const token = this.service.getTokenSession();
  event.xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
  this.confirmationService.confirm({
    message: 'Are you sure to continue?',
    header : 'Confirmation',
    accept : () => {
      this.service.showLoader();
      this.onUpload(event);
    },
    reject: () => {}
  });
}

onUpload(event): void {
  this.msgsPage = [];
  try {
    const response = JSON.parse(event.xhr.response);
    console.log(response)
    if (!response.ok) {
      this.errorModalService.show('There was an error');
      this.flagResultLoadErrors = true;
      let c = 0;
      for (let msg of response.map.errors) {
        c++;
        this.msgsPage.push({
          detail  : msg,
          severity: 'error',
          summary : 'Error ' + c,
        });
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    this.errorModalService.show('Unknown error');
    console.log(e)
  } finally {
    this.service.hideLoader();
  }
}
```

With this, I tried to block the request, but it didn't happen, what I got is that the file is sent to the server before the confirmation dialog.
Also, I'm getting this error when I tried to get the `response`:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

Hope you can help me.

Comment: it seems something wrong with confirmation service

Answer (score 1):

You can't block from that event. It is just an event emitted from the component.

https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/fileupload/fileupload.ts#L367

You will need to use the custom `uploadHandler`.

```
<p-fileUpload name="myfile[]" customUpload="true" (uploadHandler)="myUploader($event)"></p-fileUpload>
```

```
myUploader(event) {
    //event.files == files to upload
}
```

---

`SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input`

This one means the response you are getting from the xhr response is not JSON, but you are trying to parse it. Check network tab to see what the response from the server is.